# Finding kernel and image of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \{W \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) ~|~ A~ \text{is symmetric} \}$ given by the following rules

$1+x \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

$1-x \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

$x-x^2 \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Determine the $\text{ker}(S)$ and $\text{im}(S)$

Workings:

I'm not to sure on what to do

I know that $\text{ker}(S) = \{v \in V | S(v) = 0 \}$

$\text{ker}(S) = \{v \in P_2(\mathbb{R}) | S(v) = 0 \}$

So I think that I have to set the matrices to 0. But there are 3 atrices so i don't know what that means

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint** The three polynomials $p_i$ together comprise a basis of $P_2(\Bbb R)$, so any element $q$ of that space can be written as $a_1 p_1 + a_2 p_2 + a_3 p_3$. Now, write out $S(q)$ in terms of the coefficients $a_i$.

Comment: Wait there was some info I didn't give (which I will add to the post after). Let $A=\{1+x,1−x,x−x^2\}⊂P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $B = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \} \subset M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I found $M_T$ in a previous question. And I believe the  $Null(M_T)=Ker(T)$. Could I possibly do that?

Comment: Yes, the null space of the transformation matrix $M_T$ (w.r.t. a given basis!) can be identified with $\ker T$. So you could certainly write down $M_T$, this is more or less what it means to "write $S(q)$ in terms of the coefficients $a_i$", it simply adds another layer of packaging to the available data.